# Projection in OpenGl (bug with z-axis)

Tags: opengl, projection, perspective, z-axis

I don't know why but it seems my z-axis is bugged (it seems it is doubling the value or something)

This is supposed to be a cube

https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t34.0-12/11998230_879538255460372_61658668_n.jpg?oh=dd08fee0a66e37bf8f3aae2fba107fa1&oe=55F6170C

However it seems like it is "bigger in depth" what seems wrong

My pr_Matrix:

```
    mat4 mat4::prespective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float near, float far){
        mat4 result;

        float yScale = 1.0f / tan(toRadians(fov/2.0f));
        float xScale = yScale / aspectRatio;

        float frustumLength = far - near;

        result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = xScale;
        result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = yScale;
        result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = -(far + near) / frustumLength;
        result.elements[3 + 2 * 4] = -1.0f;
        result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = -(2.0f * far * near) / frustumLength;

        return result;
    }
```

My ml_Matrix:

```
        maths::mat4 &ProjectionMatrix(){

            maths::mat4 m_ProjM = maths::mat4::identity();

            m_ProjM *= maths::mat4::translation(m_Position);

            m_ProjM *= maths::mat4::rotation(m_Rotation.x, maths::vec3(1, 0, 0));
            m_ProjM *= maths::mat4::rotation(m_Rotation.y, maths::vec3(0, 1, 0));
            m_ProjM *= maths::mat4::rotation(m_Rotation.z, maths::vec3(0, 0, 1));

            maths::mat4 scale_matrix = maths::mat4(m_Scale);
            scale_matrix.elements[3 + 3 * 4] = 1.0f;

            m_ProjM *= scale_matrix;
            return m_ProjM;
        }
```

My vw_matrix (camera)

```
        void update(){
            maths::mat4 newMatrix = maths::mat4::identity();
            newMatrix *= maths::mat4::rotation(m_Pitch, maths::vec3(1, 0, 0));
            newMatrix *= maths::mat4::rotation(m_Yaw, maths::vec3(0, 1, 0));
            newMatrix *= maths::mat4::translation(maths::vec3(-m_Pos.x, -m_Pos.y, -m_Pos.z));
            m_ViewMatrix = newMatrix;
        }
```

My Matrix Multiplication in the glsl code:

```
vec4 worldPosition = ml_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
vec4 positionRelativeToCamera = vw_matrix * worldPosition;
gl_Position = pr_matrix * positionRelativeToCamera;
```

**Edit:** I think I got it! (Will double check maths once I get time) Most tutorials(so, the source of my code) use a mat4::prespective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float near, float far), the thing they don't say is that "fov" means "fovy" (so "vertical field of view"), the results seem to replicate the "usual fov in games" now with this simple change:

```
        float xScale = 1.0f / tan(toRadians(fov/2.0f));
        float yScale = xScale * aspectRatio;
```

Thanks for pointing it out as a fov problem [Henk De Boer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5160486/henk-de-boer)

Comment: What do you pass as "fov" in the prespective function.

Comment: This is my function call "mat4 proj = mat4::prespective(80.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);" so 80.0f

Comment: Try putting that to something lower, should help. Say 45-60.

Comment: That seems very good, thanks. But is this the same "fov slider" we see in games? Because 45-60 seems pretty low if it is

Comment: Yes it is, but you will find that once you have an actual scene, the results of 80 fov may not be as drastic as it looks with just the cube. Also, to add to the confusion, some games advertise the fov as 2*therealfov, so when they say that the fov is 90, it's really 45. I've posted this as an answer.

Comment: Check my edit, I think I found the "real problem" (it wasn't really a problem since you pointed me to fov, but it "explains the numbers)

Comment: To be honest I never even thought about swapping the two to be able to use horizontal FOV. I've always just tinkered with the values till it looked good :) GJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a result of FOV, the FOV you supply greatly alters the way an image looks. It's a matter of personal taste what you choose. To get a natural feeling scene anything between 45-60 is good, but you can enhance this to make the scene feel more immediate or the action more fast paced. Observe how the following image has twice the exact same geometry, but the dock to the right is protruding much further in to the viewport with a 90 degree FOV.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example and for giving me a solution!

Comment: Oh, I tried to mark it as useful but still can't, didn't even notice that, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that in declaring:

```
mat4 result;
```

You're invoking a default constructor that's initialising the matrix to identity.

Then in the subsequent code that sets up the matrix, you need a call to:

```
result.elements[3 + 3 * 4] = 0.0f;
```

Also, for what it's worth, in my code the lines:

```
result.elements[3 + 2 * 4] = -1.0f;
result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = -(2.0f * far * near) / frustumLength;
```

Are not negated. TBH, I'm not sure if that's anything to worry about.

Comment: My mat4 constructor puts every element to 0 (unless i put a float as parameter, then everything is 0 except every element of the diagonal that becomes that float) so I don't need to call "result.elements[3 + 3 * 4] = 0.0f;".  I trying to play with those "-" but It only worked this way